# Django mobile template detection with nginx and varnish

Tags: nginx, varnish, django

I'm trying to get [`django-mobile`](https://github.com/gregmuellegger/django-mobile) (uses different template namespace depending on device type) when behind varnish and nginx. I thought I had it figured out, but with my current set up, it seems that nginx only sets the cookie and not the header when using query parameters, so things change only after an additional reload.

The reason it's so complicated is so that varnish can cache two versions of the page (full & mobile) for a given url.

#### varnish config

```
sub vcl_hash {
    hash_data(req.http.X-Flavour); 
    hash_data(req.url);
    if (req.http.host) {
        hash_data(req.http.host);
    } else {
        hash_data(server.ip);
    }
    return (hash);
}
```

#### nginx config

```
location / {
    # default flavour
    set $flavour "full"; 

    # autodetect mobile flavour
    if ($http_user_agent ~* "(android|bb\d+|meego).+mobile|avantgo|bada\/|blackberry|blazer|compal|elaine|fennec|hiptop|iemobile|ip(hone|od)|iris|kindle|lge |maemo|midp|mmp|mobile.+firefox|netfront|opera m(ob|in)i|palm( os)?|phone|p(ixi|re)\/|plucker|pocket|psp|series(4|6)0|symbian|treo|up\.(browser|link)|vodafone|wap|windows ce|xda|xiino") {
        set $flavour "mobile";
    }

    # get previously set flavour from cookie
    if ($cookie_flavour) {
        set $flavour $cookie_flavour;
    }

    # actively changing flavours with ?flavour=xxx
    if ($arg_flavour ~* 'full|mobile') {
        set $flavour $arg_flavour;
        add_header Set-Cookie "flavour=$arg_flavour; Path=/";
    }

    # set header for varnish to vary on
    proxy_set_header X-Flavour $flavour;
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8000/;
}
```

I then have custom middleware that checks for the header, query args or cookies to figure out which flavor to serve.

I know that [if is evil](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/depth/ifisevil/), so I'm wondering if that's the problem here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that the configuration posted here (which is my local workstation) is not what I pasted on the server. Once I made sure it was identical everything worked. Silly me.

Answer (score 0):

Do mobile detection in Vanish itself, rather than rely on nginx. It sees everything nginx sees. You can create headers in it easily as well;

So, for example;

```
#Set http header
sub vcl_recv {
    if req.http.User-Agent ~ "iP(hone|od|ad)" || req.http.User-Agent ~ "Android" ) {
                set req.http.X-Device = "smart";
        }
}

# Use it for object hashing
sub vcl_hash {
        # If we've set a device hint header, cache based on it
        if ( req.http.X-Device ) { hash_data(req.http.X-Device); }
}
```

All you need to do now is add to that initial regex, or add different conditionals with an elseif

Comment: The reason I chose to do the detection in nginx is because varnish doesn't do cookie parsing (as far as I know) which is really annoying. And I need it so users could explicitly switch between versions if they wanted to.

Comment: You can parse cookies! There are vmods to help, but otherwise, just run regex against req.http.Cookie ?